# deinterlace video when playing with IJKPlayer

Tags: android, ijkplayer

There are exact four entries when searching google about deinterlaced play back with IJKPlayer. The best one seems to be [this](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer/issues/724). However, the mentioned solution by adding

```
mediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "vf0", "yadif")
```

to the code doesn't seem to work. Of course, when using ffplay (or ffmpeg) it's all about filters beeing included or not. So, is there any working solution available, which deinterlaces with IJKPlayer and tells which filters to use (during compiletime and runtime), idiot-proof?

EDIT:

I found, that the player has been compiled with --disable-avfilter. I checked out the latest version from git and compiled it with --enable-avfilter. Now, directory android/contrib/build/ffmpeg-armv7a/output/lib contains libavfilter.a, also. libijkffmpeg.so is bigger in size and running

```
nm -D --defined-only libijkffmpeg.so
```

shows the symbol vf_yadif. However, IJKPlayer still doesn't deinterlace when using with option vf0/yadif.

I added version info for avfilter, too:

```
I/IJKMEDIA: ===== versions =====
I/IJKMEDIA: ijkplayer    : k0.8.0
I/IJKMEDIA: FFmpeg       : ff3.3--ijk0.8.0--20170518--001
I/IJKMEDIA: libavutil    : 55.58.100
I/IJKMEDIA: SDL_RunThread: [32440] ff_msg_loop
I/IJKMEDIA: libavcodec   : 57.89.100
I/IJKMEDIA: libavformat  : 57.71.100
I/IJKMEDIA: libavfilter  : 6.82.100
I/IJKMEDIA: libswscale   : 4.6.100
I/IJKMEDIA: libswresample: 2.7.100
```

Comment: I found the following files in the IJKPlayer sources: ./android/contrib/ffmpeg-armv7a/libavfilter/vf_yadif.c
./android/contrib/ffmpeg-armv7a/libavfilter/yadif.h
I wonder, how yadif can be activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for it:

This is how to use deinterlacing with IJKPlayer on android:

- Get the lates source of IJKPlayer from GIT with

  `git clone https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer.git`
- In the newly created directory, go to config.
- Open the module*.sh file you like and enable filtering:

  `export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-avfilter"`

  `export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-filters"`
- Now, go to ijkplayer/ijkmedia and open config.h. In config.h remove the following lines:

`// FIXME: merge filter related code and enable it
    // remove these lines to enable avfilter
    #ifdef CONFIG_AVFILTER
    #undef CONFIG_AVFILTER
    #endif
    #define CONFIG_AVFILTER 0`

- Build the player as described in README.md.

The player now supports deinterlacing by setting:

```
mediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "vf0", "yadif");
```

This has to be done before mediaPlayer.start().

Since deinterlacing is a time consuming job, I had to play with the yadif options, to get it running on my device, nicely. I'm using it with `"yadif=2"`. See the official FFmpeg documentation for more details about yadif.